# Else statement inside Google Sheets IFS statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got an IFS statement in a column header to calculate some numbers based on a Google Forms input.
I would like to modify one of these column headers to include a check against a boolean and output the results based on this, I'm not sure how to include an ELSE statement inside the IFS statement.

Here is the current code:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IFS(
    ROW(A:A)=1, "NET",
    LEN(A:A)=0, IFERROR(1/0),
    LEN(A:A)>0, F:F-E:E
  )
)
```

I would like to modify this to include a boolean check before `LEN(A:A)>0, F:F-E:E`

so: `(D:D)=TRUE, B:B` ELSE `LEN(A:A)>0, F:F-E:E`

Hope someone can help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IFS, you can simulate an ELSE using the TRUE condition as the last condition, because the first TRUE result returns the given value - something like: IFS(<condition 1>, <answer 1>, <condition 2>, <answer 2>, TRUE, <default answer>)
But to have an "else if", it's just one more condition of the IFS.
I suppose you mean: IF ROW(A:A)=1 ... ELSE IF LEN(A:A)=0 ... ELSE IF (D:D)=TRUE ... ELSE IF LEN(A:A)>0 ...
Hence, try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IFS(
    ROW(A:A)=1, "NET",
    LEN(A:A)=0, IFERROR(1/0),
    (D:D)=TRUE, B:B,
    LEN(A:A)>0, F:F-E:E
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use in row 1:

```
={"NET"; INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IF(D2:D=TRUE, B2:B, F2:F-E2:E)))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can put `TRUE` statement at the end like:

```
=IFS(condition1, value1, [condition2, value2...], TRUE, 0)
```

The last condition always be true, so the `else statement` (or `default value`) is `0`.